# C# websocket never retrieves data

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm trying to imitate a browser from my console application reading from websockets

```
var tParam = "MoC4gE6";
var sessionId = GetSid(tParam); // simple GET, works the same way as in a browser
HttpGetSomeBytes(sessionId, tParam); // simple GET, return the same bytes as it is in a browser

 var uri2 = new Uri($"ws://{_host}/driver.socket/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid={sessionId}");
var ws2 = new ClientWebSocket();
Random rand = new Random();

Byte[] randomBytes = new Byte[16];

rand.NextBytes(randomBytes);

ws2.Options.SetRequestHeader("Host", _host);
ws2.Options.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
ws2.Options.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36");
await ws2.ConnectAsync(uri2, CancellationToken.None);

ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);

var receiveTask =  await ws2.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
```

The problem is that call *ReceiveAsync* never returns back.
The server is not mine so I can't check what's going on there.

**Update**:

I'm able to see 2 responses:

If I send '2' I received '3' as in a browser

If I send '2probe' I received '3probe' as in a browser

Bu when I send '5' expecting to get back some useful data (as I do in a browser) the *ReceiveAsync* never returns.

Comment: Have you tried to look at methods for error handling? Like when to close the connection, or seeing if the connection is still open?

Comment: @Train please see my updates on the question. Could you explain, please?

Comment: Can you provide the source code for the other end of the connection ?Also you can test using the `Chrome` extension : `Simple Websocket Client`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian I don't have a source code of the server.
When I try to send a message via simple websocket client it gives me
_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.js:105)
    at HTMLButtonElement.handle (jquery-1.4.3.min.js:63)
    at HTMLButtonElement.n (jquery-1.4.3.min.js:56)_